# How to add static IP in lumia 630

Tags: 8.1, lumia, settings, wifi, nokia-lumia-630

how can i add static IP in Nokia Lumia 630 ??

Currently there is no option in settings. Is there any other way where i can directly insert static IP in system through any software ??

Comment: Where do you want to use the static IP? If you are talking at home on your own wireless network then your router should be able to reserve an IP address for your phone based on its MAC address.

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings > wifi. On the bottom of the screen, you would see a button >Static IP. Click on the button, and you would be able to specify the IP address, the subnet mask, the gateway and the DNS.

I have been using the same behind my corporate proxy and DNS, which have DHCP turned off and require each connecting device to have a static IP.

[image]

Comment: Yes, feature of Static IP came after Denim update (Y)

Comment: I can't see this on my 830 fully updated beyond Denim.

Comment: can't either on my 930 on Dev preview. What phone are you using? Did you get the WP8.1 Update 2 (the one with the settings jumplists)?

Comment: I am using Lumia 625. And No, I am yet to get the update 2. This option has been there for quite a while for me, even before Denim. IIRC, this came as a small update to my phone much before Denim update. I, in fact, updated denim using a static IP. I am not in the Dev preview program.

Comment: This option isn't on all phones it seems, or perhaps it only shows after connecting to a network without DHCP enabled? (in other words, I don't see it on my 1020, either)

Comment: @RowlandShaw. I can see it an about 5-6 windows phones of my colleagues. Also, The phone does NOT connect to the network at all if DHCP is disabled and Static IP is not configured. There is, therefore, no question of an option appearing after the fact.

Comment: @VaibhavGarg Fair enough, it's just not showing as an option for Thomas, Vitor or myself, all on Denim, with three different handsets, so it may be possible that "something" additional needs to be done to enable it, or that it is handset specific

Comment: This does not apply to Lumia 950XL. Need to set the DNS server statically, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This feature seems to be availiable only for certain phones with Windows Phone 8.1. See also the suggestion for this feature on the [Windows Phone UserVoice](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3870199-windows-phone-8-static-ip-configuration-and-vpn-su) site.

Comment: There is a comment on there that links to [an app](https://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=579706af-8d22-4d0c-9222-585072ad2aab) that claims to support adding static IP networks

Comment: This has been added to windows phone 8.1, even before Denim update. I use it every day to connect to our corporate network. See my answer.

Comment: Hm, I'm not seeing that button. Could you perhaps share a screenshot so I know what to look for?

Comment: @Thomas, I surely can. BTW I did not get a notification of the comment, as I am neither the OP nor the answerer(you are!).